# How to make a simulation for wireless power transfer circuit in HFSS (High Frequency Structural Simulator) software?

Tags: simulation, electromagnetism, software

I want to simulate a circuit of wireless power transfer consisting of two resonating coils along with a loop with each coil. I am stuck with introducing a coil in HFSS.

Comment: Is this and your previous question related - if so then you should consider deleting the one that is the most inappropriate because if you don't someone else will likely do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simulation may be a little difficult to get hold of free AND particularly when you want to model 2 coils in 3D and very the distance between the two. Don't get me wrong, there are models but they are thousands and thousands of dollars.

Why don't you consider a mathematical approach: -

[image]

The transmitter coil has N turns and a current of I amperes and the current can be calculated (when resonant with a parallel C) quite easily. This tells you the flux density at a distance Z. With a bit of hand waving you can assume that the receiver coil will largely (at distance Z) receive a constant flux density thru it's coil and it becomes a fairly simple and predictable task to calculate the voltage induced in the coil. This can yield comparison results and cost nothing.

The difficult bit is when you want to see the voltage magnification due to tuning the secondary coil because this creates a counter-magnetic field that tends to reduce the primary magnetic field but, given you know what open circuit voltage is induced in the receive coil you can use LTSpice to simulate the complexities of the coupling of the two mag fields - run it as a transformer with low coupling factor to get the induced voltage then try adding a resonating cap in LTS to get an idea of the magnification due to tuning.

Comment: The OP stated that they're using HFSS, which is an expensive 3D field solver.